# Added the information from the last element to the end of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

My question is rather simple. I am attempting to add the last element of an arrayList to the end of that array list with a line like:

```
   ArrayList.add(ArrayList.get(ArrayList.size()));
```

but what I am given is an indexOutOfBoundsException.

SO is there a way to do this without landing an exception? quick answers. This line is not contained in any loops. The arrayList has size. I have tried it with ArrayList.size()-1 to no avail here is the full block of code it is contained in.

```
public class SaveButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
        int status = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            String fileName = selectedFile.getPath();
            File imageFolder = new File(fileName);
            imageFolder.mkdir();

            //tokenizes the path into an arraylist
            String delims = "/";
            ArrayList<String> fileTokensList = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] fileTokens = fileName.split(delims);
            fileTokensList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fileTokens));

            //adds the name of the current image
            fileTokensList.add(fileTokensList.get(fileTokensList.size()));

            //rebuilds all the tokens into one string path
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int s = 0; s < fileTokensList.size(); s++) {
                if (s == 0) {
                    builder.append(fileTokensList.get(s));
                } else {
                    builder.append("/");
                    builder.append(fileTokensList.get(s));
                }
            }
            String textFileName = builder.toString();
            System.out.println(textFileName);
            try {
                File saveFile = new File(textFileName);
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(saveFile);
                try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Driver.vehicleList.size()+1; i++) {

                        //writes the text file (one entry per line
                        bufferedWriter.write(Driver.vehicleList.get(i).getPrice());
                        bufferedWriter.write("\t");
                        bufferedWriter.write(Driver.vehicleList.get(i).getYear());
                        bufferedWriter.write("\t");
                        bufferedWriter.write(Driver.vehicleList.get(i).getMake());
                        bufferedWriter.write("\t");
                        bufferedWriter.write(Driver.vehicleList.get(i).getModel());
                        bufferedWriter.write("\t");
                        bufferedWriter.write(Driver.vehicleList.get(i).getComments());
                        bufferedWriter.newLine();

                        //adds the name of the current image
                        fileTokensList.add(Integer.toString(i));

                        //rebuilds all the tokens into one string path
                        StringBuilder imagePathBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int s = 0; s < fileTokensList.size(); s++) {
                            if (s == 0) {
                                imagePathBuilder.append(fileTokensList.get(s));
                            } else {
                                imagePathBuilder.append("/");
                                imagePathBuilder.append(fileTokensList.get(s));
                            }
                        }
                        String imageFileName = builder.toString();

                        //resaves the picture to the same place 
                        Path FROM =         Paths.get(Driver.vehicleList.get(i).getCarPicture());
                        Path TO = Paths.get(imageFileName);
                        //overwrite existing file, if exists
                        CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
                            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
                            StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
                        };
                        Files.copy(FROM, TO, options);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException IO) {
                System.out.println("Error writing to file");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All your information has been saved");
        }
    }
}
```

This chunk of code is meant to save a file to a location and i do a lot of messing with tokens and rebuilding of that path. am I taking the long way to an easy solution or am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList.get(int index)` will work if the `index` value is between 0 and `Array.size() - 1`. Since you're sending `Array.size()`, you're going to a non valid location of the array, thus getting the exception.

How to solve this? Well, you should post what you're trying to add and you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> fileTokensList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Your list contains strings so you need to get the size of the list and convert it to a String before you add it to the list.

```
list.add( list.size() + "")
```

One way to do this is to use the "+" concatenation operator and the compiler will automatically create a String for you.

Comment: I am trying to add the information in the last element to the end of the array not the size of the array (my bad on the title)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
ArrayList.add(ArrayList.get(ArrayList.size()));
```

to

```
ArrayList.add(ArrayList.get(ArrayList.size()-1));
```

Comment: I did and it proceeds but nothing appears at the end

Comment: @BlaineShelton I think a little debugging might help you, first check out what is returned by `fileTokensList.get(fileTokensList.size()-1)` and then if it succeeds with what you want go with next step of storing it in some variable and then add.